# Cant get label and input to work on focus

Tags: html, css, forms, animation, label

I want to get the label on top of the input. But when I move it up in the code the CSS Focus styles stop working. On focus the label needs gets bigger. How to fix this? tried everything...

```css
form {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

input {
  
  display:block;
}

form input:focus + label {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  
    <!-- DOESN'T WORK
=====================
-->
  <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">

  <br>
  
  <!-- WORKS 
=====================
-->
  <input id="lasttname" name="firstname" type="text">
  <label for="lasttname">Last name:</label>


</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap label and input in extra `div`, and use `flex-box`:

```css
form {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
form input:focus + label {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.form-row label {
   order: 1;
}

.form-row input {
   order: 2; 
   width: 141px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  
    <!-- DOESN'T WORK
=====================
-->
  <div class='form-row'>
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
  </div>

  <!-- WORKS 
=====================
-->
  <input id="lasttname" name="firstname" type="text">
  <label for="lasttname">Last name:</label>


</form>
```

Comment: Works but now how to get the label on top of the field? this I cant understand..... Because the label is under I cant use BLOCK to get it up....

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin oh, I didn't get first what you wanted. I edited my answer, now it written in `flexbox`, should work fine.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you a lot!) Can it be done without flex?

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin Well, if your labels will have an equal height, when it can be done with `position:absolute`. But I think `flexbox` is a great feature and you should use it. It supported by [94% of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) currently.

Answer (score 2):

An jQuery solution.

```js
$(function() {
  $('form input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).prev('label').css("font-size", "1.5em");
  });
  $('form input[type="text"]').focusout(function() {
    $(this).prev('label').css("font-size", "1em");
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
form input:focus + label {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <!-- DOESN'T WORK
=====================
-->
  <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">

  <!-- WORKS 
=====================
-->
  <input id="lasttname" name="firstname" type="text">
  <label for="lasttname">Last name:</label>


</form>
```